# How to get path to save a file from user?

Tags: java

I'm developing an application in which I want to create an 'MS-EXCEL' file and for that I want the name for the file to be given by user and later on I want to provide an option to the user to save at the path where it wants.
  I know about JFileChooser but it only allows to select a file from the existing files whereas I want to save. What can be the way? Please give me some brief description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full example on FileChooser you find [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java)

Comment: Thank You! :) I referred to the example, but there is one doubt about ImageIcon. Why it is used for JButton and why SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Thread t) is used? Can You please tell?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode` to allow selection of either files, directories, or both files and directories.

You can also type in the name of a file that doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        // do soemthing
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the JFileChooser's [showSaveDialog()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog%28java.awt.Component%29) method?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a JDirectoryChooser.  Sounds to easy!

Comment: Ha! That's a nice idea but virtual!! :)